# How to save Image to storage using Glide on button click?

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm showing images from server with glide into recyclerview. when user click on image, it shows full image. I want that user can save that image on button click.

```
 imageViewPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);

        Photos image = images.get(position);
        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(image.getUrl())
                .thumbnail(Glide.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.loader))
                .fitCenter()
                .crossFade()
                .into(imageViewPreview);
```

Comment: so you basically want to get bitmap from the imageview

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405224/save-image-once-glide-has-loaded-it

Comment: @quicklearner i want to load image into imageview . if user click on save button than image should be saved .

Comment: you can directly save image when it loads and show a toast/alert when user click on button and if user doesnt click on button you can delete the file IF YOU WANT TO USE GLIDE ONLY

Comment: @quicklearner I cant do that, it's a wallpaper type app.

Comment: added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SmartPhoto");
    boolean success = false;




public void SaveImage() {
            final Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            final String fname = "image" + n + ".png";
            myDir.mkdirs();
            File image = new File(myDir, fname);

            imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Imgv.getDrawingCache();
            // Encode the file as a PNG image.
            FileOutputStream outStream;
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                        /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
                success = true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (success) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.savedimage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.errorloadingimage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                final Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                final Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
                scanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
            } else {
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://mnt/sdcard/" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            }
        }
```

Comment: just in Toast,,,import the other

Comment: //uncoment this line   ImageView Imgv = (ImageView) mPager.findViewWithTag(mPager.getCurrentItem());

Comment: what is `myDir`? what is `mPager`? Why some variables are named against Java code conventions?

Comment: what is `Imgv`? Also it will save not the original image, but only the drawing cache. So if your ImageView size is 200x200 px, and original image is 2000x2000, it will save 200x200
I'm not the one who asked a question. I'm not going to use it.

Comment: updated use it again..if fit your need mark the answer as correct@Mukesh Soni

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172291/discussion-between-al-tegani-and-vladyslav-matviienko).

Answer (score 5):

if you want to load an image using Glide and save it then you can use Glide in this manner:

```
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/quwoe.jpg")
                    .asBitmap()
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                            saveImage(resource);
                        }
                    });

    //code to save the image 

        private void saveImage(Bitmap resource) {

            String savedImagePath = null;
            String imageFileName =  "image" + ".jpg";


            final File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                    "/Pics");

            boolean success = true;
            if(!storageDir.exists()){
                success = storageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            if(success){
                File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
                savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
                try {
                    OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Add the image to the system gallery
                galleryAddPic(savedImagePath);
                Toast.makeText(this, "IMAGE SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    // Add the image to the system gallery
        private void galleryAddPic(String imagePath) {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            File f = new File(imagePath);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        }
```

Comment: you can show the image using Glide by making use of -->         .into("Your image-view"), but using the "into" function of Glide for saving as well as displaying cannot be done simultaneously, according to me. Kindly, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: How to get gif in onResourceReady as Bitmap only holds single frame. (not for showing but saving the gif)

Answer (score 0):

you can try loading as a bitmap before you call the into(imageViewPreview)

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
  .load(image.getUrl())
  .asBitmap()
  ... rest of your stuffs
```

then to access the bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageViewPreview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are many ways to achieve this out if that there is one simplest solution is to use `UniversalIMageLoader` here is the implementation guide [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Here is the implementation that how to download the image

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(
            "IMAGE URL",
            new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {
                    //SHOW PROGRESS
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    //HIDE PROGRESS
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    //HIDE PROGRESS

                    //Use this Bitmap to save in to galler

                    FileOutputStream out = null;
                    try {
                        out = new FileOutputStream("FILE_NAME");
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
                        // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            if (out != null) {
                                out.close();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {
                    //HIDE PROGRESS
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Universal Image Loader library uses Android's BitmapFactory.decodeStream which is buggy in case of unreliable network and user may see half empty image. Glide does not use that hence always a better option.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for this**

```
  // DownloadImage AsyncTask
    private class DownloadImageCertIV extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

            String imageURL = URL[0];

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                // Download Image from URL
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
                // Decode Bitmap
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

                if (result != null) {


                    File destination = new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(),
                            "your path" + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        destination.createNewFile();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
                        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                        fos.write(bitmapdata);
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        }
```

**To use this on button click**

```
 new DownloadImageCertIV().execute("URL HERE");
```

Comment: How to save gif. bitmap is for static image as it holds single frame